Dynamic data range column in formula based on header value in google sheets
Problem: I need to summarize hundreds of sheets that all contain the same column header but are not always on the same column number. Is there a smart way to get the column for a range based on what the header row says (always row 2)?
=COUNTIFS(
(importrange(B2, "Form Responses 1!Q3:Q")),"YES",
(importrange(B2, "Form Responses 1!Y3:Y")),""
)

Essentially this would summarize the quantity of pending items on a sheet for my team. Checks if the line item is approved to action and the status of it being actioned.
where B2 is the link of the targeted spreadsheet
where Q is the indication that a form response requires action (need to be dynamic based on header name "Approved")
where Y is the indication that that line item has been actioned (need to be dynamic based on header name "Task")

This approach uses two IMPORTRANGE calls to each Sheet.  The first is for the label row to identify the correct row numbers. The second is for smallest range possible that includes both those columns.
Alternative approaches could use 3 calls and pull the individual columns only but I'm assuming this strikes a balance and the performance will be adequate.
If the various sheets are in the same spreadsheet then IMPORTRANGE should not be used at all and a new question should be asked.
Sample Source Data




A
B
C
D




1
Count Formula

Spreadsheet ID
Sheet Name


2
?

1HjUjyOhmnD7Jwo3Z_GiSH-KqZmNhRySX_Mkv5ixF3PM
Form Responses 2


3
?

1Y6ERMRIhjjf-bAQJWMjf3mcP4niC1c99rrqZ9sCZwZs
Form Responses 1


4
?

1g0beVc4axI6OH_XhESP2Kh0i53dzGp5RSbD-NPwsVK0
Form Responses 3



Return Single Count

Formula in A2

=INDEX(LET(
  val,"Yes", id,C2, sht,D2, lbl,{"YesCol","EmptyCol"},
  imp,LAMBDA(r, IMPORTRANGE(id, "'"& sht &"'!"& r)),  
  num,LAMBDA(h, FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h)), COUNTIF(lbl,h)))(imp("2:2")),
  off,INDEX(num,,2)-INDEX(num,,1)+1,  
  ref,JOIN(":", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,num,4),1,)& {3,""}),
  SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(QUERY(imp(ref), "Where Col1 ='"& val &
    "' AND Col"& off &" = ''"))<>"")))

ADDRESS  COLUMNS  COUNTIF  FILTER  IFNA  IMPORTRANGE  INDEX  JOIN  LAMBDA  LET  QUERY  SEQUENCE  SUBSTITUTE  SUMPRODUCT

Return Array of Counts

Formula in A2

=INDEX(LET(
  rng,C2:D, val,"Yes", lbl,{"YesCol","EmptyCol"},
  arr,QUERY(rng, "Where Col1 is not Null"),
  ids,INDEX(arr,,1), shts,INDEX(arr,,2), 
  MAP(ids, shts, LAMBDA(i,s, LET(
    imp,LAMBDA(r, IMPORTRANGE(i, "'"& s &"'!"& r)),  
    num,LAMBDA(h, FILTER(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(h)),COUNTIF(lbl,h)))(imp("2:2")),
    off,INDEX(num,,2)-INDEX(num,,1)+1,  
    ref,JOIN(":", SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,num,4),1,)& {3,""}),
    SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(QUERY(imp(ref), "Where Col1 ='"& val 
      &"' AND Col"& off &" =''"))<>""))))))

ADDRESS  COLUMNS  COUNTIF  FILTER  IFNA  IMPORTRANGE  INDEX  JOIN  LAMBDA  LET  MAP  QUERY  SEQUENCE  SUBSTITUTE  SUMPRODUCT

Explanation
Return Single Count

The value to check for, references to the spreadsheet ID, sheet name, and the column labels to match are stored in val, id, sht, and lbl respectively.
imp is used to store a LAMBDA function to be used later:

The LAMBDA function stores the range reference it is passed in r.
The LAMBDA's formula returns the result of IMPORTRANGE using the values of id, sht and the r that was passed in.
For example, imp("2:2") would be equivalent to
IMPORTRANGE(id, "'"& sht &"'!"& "2:2")




num returns an array of two numbers, each representing index of one of the column labels you are trying to match:

A LAMBDA function passes imp("2:2") into its formula as h
FILTER is applied to a SEQUENCE numbering from 1 up to the total number of columns in h
COUNTIF is used as the condition where the values in h must match one of the values in lbl


off stores the number of columns between the first matched column and the second for use in the QUERY later.
ref stores a string representing the minimum range reference that includes the first matched column and the second.
Finally QUERY is applied to the imported range imp(ref) returning  the two matched columns where the first matches val and the second is empty.

The first matched column is always Col1 because that is the first column in ref
The second matched column is "Col"& off because off is that column's offset from Col1.
The QUERY is wrapped in IFNA to handle the error in case there are no matches
The result is placed inside SUMPRODUCT and compared to to an empty value in order to return the count.
SUMPRODUCT was used specifically because it will give you feedback if either of the column labels don't actually exist in the sheet by passing through the through a #REF! error, assuming you want a visual cue.  You could wrap that in IFERROR to return a custom error message if you prefer.



Return Array of Counts

Uses the functionality from the previous formula but repeats it for each row of data you have.
rng is an infinite range reference containing the id and sht columns from the previous formula
arr removes any empty rows from rng
ids and shts are column 1 and 2 of arr respectively
MAP is used to pass each  row from ids and  shts, row-by-row into a LAMBDA function that stores the current row's values in i and s respectively.
The LAMBDA's  formula then repeats items 2 to 6 of the previous explanation but replaces references to id by i and sht by s.
7 This LAMBDA's formula is repeated for each row mapped in resulting in an array of counts or errors if a labeled column was missing.


FYI my example column labels {"YesCol","EmptyCol"} should be updated to match your labels to{"Approved","Task"} Oversight on my part. Likewise "Yes" could be "Y" or another value. Also if there is label variability between the sheets, you could add the label names to the rows with the ids and sheet or only exceptions or if the sheet is always the same you could hardcode it in the formula etc.
